# Update function in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am currently trying to create a new fleet manager for work and have run into a small problem.

I am looking in vain for the possibility to replace the value of a SVERWEIS (VLOOKUP) path.

Currently it looks like this:

I have one sheet that lists all my drivers, which functions as a sort of "database", and one for my vehicles. Each vehicle has a driver associated with it and searching and outputting the values works but replacing the value does not yet.

**The vehicle "database" looks something like this:**

```
plate_number, main_inspection, damages, driver, driver_id;

AB123, .., John Doe, 002
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Can I ask you about the detail of it? And, in order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect as the image? By the way, in your tag, `google-apps-script` is used. Do you want to achieve your goal using Google Apps Script?

Comment: So I have a vehicle table which acts as a "database". In this table are license plate, make, driver etc. and I want to update via a button the driver which is registered to the car. The driver of the car is determined using a VLOOKUP's and my question is how I can "replace" the driver with Google Apps Scripts.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: 私は、"データベース "として機能する車両テーブルを持っています。このテーブルには、ナンバープレート、メーカー、ドライバーなどがあり、私は車に登録されているドライバーをボタンで更新したいのです。車のドライバーはVLOOKUPを使用して決定され、私の質問は、Google Appsのスクリプトでドライバーを「交換」することができます方法です。

Comment: Like Tainake I can not understand your question.  Your "database" uses VLOOKUP to get the drivers name, correct?  So you want to change the name of the driver in the sheet that contains the drivers name?  And how do you propose to change the drivers name?  What does the "button" do?

Comment: So I have a table, which acts as a 'database' and in this license plates, drivers, etc. are entered, I now let me determine the respective driver via a VLOOKUP depending on the license plate. I would like to be able to replace this driver then however over a function. My question here is, how can I do this best?